# The $\ell_2$ norm of two stochastic vectors

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, vectors, stochastic-calculus

I would like to know why this is true:

> Given an $n$-dimensional stochastic vector $v$ and another $n$-dimensional stochastic vector $u$ which distributes uniformly over $\{1,\dots,n\}$ *(meaning if the length of the vector $u$ is $n=3$ then $u = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$)* then $\lVert u-v\rVert_2 \leq 1$.

For example, let $v = (0.8,0.2)$ and $v = (0.5,0.5)$: $\lVert u-v\rVert_2 = \lVert(0.3,-0.3)\rVert_2=\sqrt{2\cdot0.3^2}$
 which is less than 1.

I tried many different inputs and it works for all of them but I can’t figure out why?

Comment: Your statement is too confusing.  Are you asking about 2-d or 3-d vectors?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I am asking for n-d vectors. the 2-d and 3-d vectors where just an example in order to simplify the problem.

Comment: There is other confusing stuff.  For example  U length 3 and U=(1/3,1/3,1/3) is wrong.  In general $|v-u|\le 1$ is not true without more descriptions for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg that's why I indicated that U distribute uniformly between 1 untill n.

Comment: If I may, why are there votes to close with no comment on it? Sure, the OP hasnt included their attempts (if any), but then the minimum here (for a new contributor) would be to point it out instead of just voting for closure... *"נירייב שמואל is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering."*

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

First, you can show it will be at most 2 by the triangle inequality, and even a bit better: for $u,v$ two $n$-dimensional vectors in the probability simplex with $u$ being uniform,
$$
 \lVert u-v\rVert_2 \leq \lVert  u\rVert_2+ \lVert v\rVert_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + 1
$$

Now, for the stronger claim. Observe that
$$\begin{align}
\lVert u-v\rVert_2^2 &= \sum_{k=1}^n (u_k-v_k)^2 = 
\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2 - 2\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k
= n\cdot \frac{1}{n^2} + \lVert v\rVert_2^2 - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n v_k\\
&= \frac{1}{n} + \lVert v\rVert_2^2 - \frac{2}{n}
= \lVert v\rVert_2^2 - \frac{1}{n} \\
&\leq 1 - \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}$$
where the last inequality comes from the fact that $$\lVert v\rVert_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^n v_k = 1$$
(more generally, $\lVert v\rVert_p \leq \lVert v\rVert_q$ if $p\geq q\geq 1$).

> **Upshot:** the squared $\ell_2$ distance of a probability vector to uniformity is equal, up to an additive factor $1/n$, to its squared $\ell_2$ norm:
>   $$
> \lVert u-v\rVert_2^2 = \lVert v\rVert_2^2 - \frac{1}{n}
> $$
>    which can itself be interpreted as the *collision probability*
>   $$
> \lVert v\rVert_2^2 = \mathbb{P}_{v}\{ X=Y\}
> $$
>   where $X,Y$ are independent random variables with pmf $v$.

Comment: Note: the reason for the last comment in the "upshot" is that this view of the $\ell_2$ distance to uniform as directly related to the collision probability is the basis for most uniformity testing algorithms (given i.i.d. realizations from a discrete r.v., decide whether its distribution is uniform vs. far from uniform). I figured it was worth mentioning.